# Regex to catch non-sense words with some rules in spanish

Tags: c#, regex

I've tried a lot of very unsuccesful patterns and I can't get the real thing.
The following attempt is **INCOMPLETE**, I'm not looking for an improvement, just a real solution for this scenario.

I'm trying to detect (return true if match) on C# (.NET 2017) the following pattern/rules:

- Insensitive match
- If one word on the string returns `true` to the pattern, all the string returns `true`
- Vowels are: `'a,e,i,o,u and y'`
- Words without any vowel, return `true`

  - Except if the word contains one or more digits, or if applies to the following case.
- Words with more than 3 not-vowels return `true`

  - Digits are counted as not-vowel in this case.
  - Exception to this rule, that the found pattern are: `bstr`,`dscr`,`dstr`,`nscr`,`nstr`,`rscr`,`nsfl`,`nsfr`,`nsgr`
- Words must not contain more than 2 same letters consecutives except for: `a`,`c`,`e`,`i`,`l`,`o`,`r`,`s`,`u`

  - Words must not contain more than 3 same letters consecutives, without exception.

My C# code is the sample one:

```
 Regex regex = new Regex(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Regex_LogicalWord"]);
            Match match = regex.Match(input);
            return match.Success
```

My regular expressions so far (not working properly):

```
\b(?:[^aeiyou\W]){1,}\b

\b(?=\w{2,}\b)(?:[^aeiou\W]*[aeiuo]){1,}[^aeiou\W]*\b

([bdfghjkmnñpqtvwxyz])\1{1}|([aceilorsu])\2{2}|[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]{5}
```

Any suggest or any help will be preciated.

The main idea is lower the performance in regex, so I assume that one pattern is my goal instead loop every word for different patterns.

Update: Examples to find and exclude:

```
NO - con la jaja jsld la la
NO - aj124312
NO - lsj
NO - aaa
NO - ºººº
NO - yyamo
NO - hoooola
NO - ferrrocarrilll
NO - reveeer
NO - llluvia
NO - djsagaklsjgklfagkljfa
NO - glalghjrjgkJGSDGg
NO - sdfsadasdfsdfsadf
NO - sadasdgjkwergjkeqjk
NO - hola llluvia
NO - dfkjlasfjklasdfgjaklsg
NO - kajfgkajfdgjkldfgj
NO - akfjgklafd
NO - asfkjgakld
NO - skadjgflkasjgñl
NO - q
YES - y
YES - 1222133123123
YES - 11111111111123213123
YES - de
YES - y etc
YES - a3 a4
YES - hola
YES - hoola
YES - ferrocarril
YES - veer
YES - reeveer
YES - lluvia
YES - 121112111111111223

YES -    Abstraer, substraer
YES -    Abstruso
YES -    Adscribir, circunscribir, inscribir y subscribir, transcribir
YES -    Adstringir
YES -    Conscripción
YES -    Constreñir
YES -    Construir
YES -    Demonstrar (variante de demostrar)
YES -    Obstrucción
YES -   Imperscrutable e inscrutable,
YES -    Instridente
YES -    Instruir
YES -    Instrumento
YES -    Menstruación
YES -    Monstruo
YES -    Obstruir
YES -    Premonstratense
YES -    Sánscrito
YES -    Transflor
YES -    Transfregar
YES -    Transfretar
YES -    Transgredir
```

Comment: Why are there different results for `aj124312` and `a3 a4`? What is the rule for `ºººº` ? What is your definition of "a word"?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte thanks for your reply. The difference between aj124312 and a3 and a4 is that the second are only two chars, one digit, one letter. The rule for º is non alphanumeric, or punctuation sign. I didn't do that example right now.

Comment: Why this `glalghjrjgkJGSDGg` should fail?

Comment: @revo because has more than 4 not-vowels in a row and that consonants are not in the exception list

Comment: Please exactly show which 4 not-vowels you mean otherwise I think it falls under `Words with more than 3 not-vowels return true` rule which should pass.

Comment: @revo thx for your reply. The rule in spanish is that there are not words with 4 or more consonants in a row, except for words that contains: bstr,dscr,dstr,nscr,nstr,rscr,nsfl,nsfr,nsgr (like "construccion")

Comment: By *in a row* don't you mean immediate only? I mean do you assume words *bbbb* and *bwbdbfbg* have *b* in a row?

Comment: @revo Thats way the rule "Words must not contain more than 2 same letters consecutives except for"

Comment: Yet I am not sure if you mean *immediately consecutive* or not...

Comment: `,`, `(`,  `)` and space are also "non alphanumeric characters" and don't seem to cause any problem. You should refine your rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that it's really hard to do, but the description is not
worded sufficiently to disambiguate.

Here is my attempt.

`(?i)(?<!\S)(?=(?:\d|([a-z])(?!\1\1\1))+(?!\S))(?=(?:([^\Waceilorsu\d_])(?!\2\2)|[aceilorsu\d])+(?!\S))(?:[^\Waeiouy_]+|(?=[a-z\d]*?(?:bstr|dscr|dstr|nscr|nstr|rscr|nsfl|nsfr))[a-z\d]*?[^\Waeiouy_](?:[a-z\d]*?[^\Waeiouy_]){2}[a-z\d]*?)(?!\S)`

Comments

```
 (?i)
 (?<! \S )                     # Whitespace boundary

 (?=                           # 3 successive max, no exceptions
      (?:
           \d 
        |  
           ( [a-z] )                     # (1)
           (?! \1 \1 \1 )
      )+
      (?! \S )
 )

 (?=                           # 2 successive max, except one of [aceilorsu]
      (?:
           ( [^\Waceilorsu\d_] )         # (2)
           (?! \2 \2 )
        |  
           [aceilorsu\d] 
      )+
      (?! \S )
 )

 (?:
      [^\Waeiouy_]+                 # No vowels 
   |                              # or,
                                    # 3 Not vowels
      (?=                           # must be one of these to qualify
           [a-z\d]*? 
           (?:
                bstr
             |  dscr
             |  dstr
             |  nscr
             |  nstr
             |  rscr
             |  nsfl
             |  nsfr 
           )
      )
      [a-z\d]*?                    
      [^\Waeiouy_] 
      (?: [a-z\d]*? [^\Waeiouy_] ){2}
      [a-z\d]*? 
 )
 (?! \S )                      # Whitespace boundary
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sln for your effort, is really a good answer, this gave me new ideas about what can I do with regex and how to work it.I know the question is maybe a little werid because the functional case i got is really a mess, but i can work with this and improve it if needed. Thanks a lot really